# Insert directive using Angular expression

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4j088sg/3/)?

I want to add a directive to an element using an Angular expression.

Example:

```
<div {{hello}}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the div inside the controller and not in the html markup in order to create directive dynamically. Over here I have used the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service inorder to dynamically generate the directive according the scope variable hello.

Controller Code:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.flag = "disabled";
    $scope.hello = "hello";
    var el = $compile("<div " + $scope.hello + "></div>")($scope);
    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#mainID'));
    element.append(el);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4j088sg/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I can see the idea but I'm not sure that's the appropriate place to declare your element.  I would stick to attributes separate by type, or like @V31 where you create elements based on directives although his example seems to just create an element after the directive has compiled, I think you would need to recompile your directive again after that.  Moreover I think the real power of your directive comes with it's ability to handle these events and maintain scope etc.

I would stick to attributes to declare your different element types, something like this -

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/e93uaqbw/)

```
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        ngModel: "=",
        type: "@"
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) { ...
```

Also ng-disabled already has an attribute for this.

```
ng-disabled="{{flag}}"
```